# How can I list the models has I brand that I selected with Json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to list in second  tag the models  of the brand I selected. I need this for my homework. I do not know what to do. Please help me.

```js
  function notlariListele(param) {
      var httpistegi = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var adres = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atakanbalta/Moto-karsilastirma/master/markalar.json";
    
    
      httpistegi.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          var list1 = document.querySelector("#slc1");
          myArr.forEach(function(params) {
            list1.innerHTML += '<option value="'+ params.marka +'">' + params.marka + '</option>';
          });
        }
      };
      httpistegi.open("GET", adres, true);
      httpistegi.send();
    }
  
    notlariListele();
```

```css
select {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="slc1"></select>
<select id="slc2"></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to load populate two drop downs from the results of an HTTP request, where the value of the first drop down determines what options appear in the second. Your response looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "marka": "BMW",
    "modeller": [
      "BMW 1000RR",
      "R 1200 Rs",
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "marka": "SUZUKI",
    "modeller": [
      "HAYABUSA",
      "RAIDER",
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Let's first simplify the question by ignoring the HTTP request, since it seems like you've got that part working. We can just hard code that result for now so we can focus on how the drop downs interact.

The key here is that when you change the value of the brand drop down, you need to re-populate the model drop down. You do this by listening to the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event of the brand drop down:

```
<select>.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  ...
});
```

Then search for the brand the user is interested in by using the value that was selected. This can be done many in ways, but for this example, we'll use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var myItem = myArr.find(function(params){ return <some condition> });
```

Putting it together, we get something like this:

```js
const jsonData = [{
    "marka": "BMW",
    "modeller": [
      "BMW 1000RR",
      "R 1200 Rs",
      "S1000rr",
      "K 1600B",
      "K 1600Gtl",
      "K 1600 gt",
      "R 1200 rt",
      "R 1200r",
      "R 1200 Gs",
      "F 750 GS",
      "G 450 X",
      "S 1000 XR"
    ]
  },
  {
    "marka": "SUZUKI",
    "modeller": [
      "HAYABUSA",
      "RAIDER",
      "GSX 1000R",
      "Gsx r1000 abs",
      "V-strom 1000",
      "V-strom  650",
      "Burgman 400z",
      "Burgman650z",
      "V-strom 250"
    ]
  },
];

const brandList = document.getElementById("brandList");
const modelList = document.getElementById("modelList");

function populateBrandList() {
  brandList.innerHTML = '';
  jsonData.forEach(function(params) {
    brandList.innerHTML += '<option value="' + params.marka + '">' + params.marka + '</option>';
  });
}
function populateModelList(brand) {
  var brandInfo = jsonData.find(function(params){ return params.marka === brand });
  if (brandInfo) {
    modelList.innerHTML = '';
    brandInfo.modeller.forEach(function(params) {
      modelList.innerHTML += '<option value="' + params + '">' + params + '</option>';
    });
  }
}

brandList.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  populateModelList(event.target.value);
});
populateBrandList();
```

```html
<select id="brandList"></select>
<select id="modelList"></select>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things to consider:

1. As your list of models are nested at the same level as the maker in the JSON object, you can use the index of that object to more efficiently find the list of models of a selected maker. That means that instead of having the value of `<option>` as your maker, you would use the index in the array. For this you will have to add the `index` parameter to your [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax): `myArr.forEach(params, index)`
2. For showing the relevant models when one item is selected, you will need to make use of the [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) JavaScript event, but also trigger this event at the start of page when `list1` is preselected with the first value.
3. For cleaner code, you will need to have access to `myArr`, `list1` and supposedly `list2` from a higher [scope](https://codeburst.io/javascript-a-basic-guide-to-scope-9682d57be6fc), so you will have to declare them outside your `onreadystatechange` event handler.

Having all the above considered, try to think how you could achieve this with the aid of the referenced links. Once you got it (or at least attempted), look at the code snippet below on how this could be achieved. Remember that there is no one unique way of resolving this issue but there are always better ways than others – this one should do pretty well by keeping coherence in your code.

```js
function notlariListele(param) {
  var httpistegi = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var adres = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atakanbalta/Moto-karsilastirma/master/markalar.json";
  var myArr; // Store array here so that it is accessible in both functions
  var list1 = document.querySelector("#slc1");
  var list2 = document.querySelector("#slc2");

  list1.onchange = function() {
    // Empty second list first
    list2.innerHTML = '';
    myArr[this.value].modeller.forEach(function(model) {
      list2.innerHTML += '<option value="' + model + '">' + model + '</option>';
    });
  }

  httpistegi.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      myArr.forEach(function(params, index) {
        list1.innerHTML += '<option value="' + index + '">' + params.marka + '</option>';
      });
      list1.onchange(); // Trigger once to populate list at first.
    }
  };
  httpistegi.open("GET", adres, true);
  httpistegi.send();


}

notlariListele();
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="slc1"></select>
<select id="slc2"></select>
```

Comment: Great walkthrough from you as well @p.s.w.g :)